# Dropping a breakpoint into a Javascript file using Firebug

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, firebug

I'm debugging a Twitter Bootstrap dropdown menu (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html) which isn't dropping down.

I'm assuming the Javascript isn't running but would like to check. My initial thought was to drop a breakpoint into bootstrap.js somewhere using Firebug. However, I can't see where to do this. If I click on the Script tab I just get a screen showing javascript.html which seems exactly the same as the HTML source code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It might be a clue if you can't find the script.... ;)

Comment: and there are no other scripts for you to select in the dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the script tab, where you see 'javascript.html', click on it (click on javascript.html) and firebug will give you a popup list of all scripts the page is using. The one you want to debug will likely be found inside the assets folder there.

[image]